# How to get click event of a tree view

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I always used Navigate URL in treeview to open a particular form. But now i want to program on a node of treeview having text LOG OUT and value LOG_OUT. On which event should i program this node ??
Dev..

Answer (score 0):

Is there a `OnNodeClick` event you can handle?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `OnSelectedNodeChanged` event but if you have a navigate url on your node, the event will not throw.